# Creating new object instance depending on input object using some map

Tags: typescript

Let's suppose that we have Commands and CommandHandlers. One CommandHandler per Command.

Now I'd like to get new instance of CommandHandler object by Command object according some map. What is the best way to define this kind of map? **Solution should work after code minification and should be refactoring-friendly.**

Currently I have this kind of solution, that I personally don't like.

```
interface Command {}
class ConcreteCommand implements Command {}
class ConcreteCommand2 implements Command {}

interface CommandHandler {}
class ConcreteCommandHandler implements CommandHandler {}
class ConcreteCommand2Handler implements CommandHandler {}

const map = [ //I don't like this kind of map, any other ways?
    [ConcreteCommand, ConcreteCommandHandler],
    [ConcreteCommand2, ConcreteCommand2Handler]
];

function getCommandHandler(command: Command): CommandHandler {
    for(let pair of map) {
        if (command instanceof pair[0]) {
            return new pair[1];
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Unable to find CommandHandler.');
}

console.log( getCommandHandler(new ConcreteCommand()) ); //ConcreteCommandHandler
```

[This code at TypeScript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Command%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteCommand%20implements%20Command%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteCommand2%20implements%20Command%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CommandHandler%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteCommandHandler%20implements%20CommandHandler%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteCommand2Handler%20implements%20CommandHandler%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20map%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BConcreteCommand%2C%20ConcreteCommandHandler%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BConcreteCommand2%2C%20ConcreteCommand2Handler%5D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getCommandHandler(command%3A%20Command)%3A%20CommandHandler%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20pair%20of%20map)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(command%20instanceof%20pair%5B0%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20pair%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error('Unable%20to%20find%20CommandHandler.')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%20getCommandHandler(new%20ConcreteCommand())%20)%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a data type called a Map. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

To use one:

```
const map = new Map()

map.set(ConcreteCommand, ConcreteCommandHandler)

const handler = new (map.get(ConcreteCommand))()
```

The caveat is that your code would not work with this because:

```
getCommandHandler(new ConcreteCommand())
```

each instance will be treated as a unique key. You can use the function itself though: `map.set(ConcreteCommand)`

Answer (score 0):

Native `Maps` are great for this:

```
const map = new Map<Command, CommandHandler>([
    [ConcreteCommand, ConcreteCommandHandler],
    [ConcreteCommand2, ConcreteCommand2Handler]
])

function getCommandHandler(command: Command): CommandHandler
{
    if (map.has(command) == false)
        throw new Error('Unable to find CommandHandler.');

    return map.get(command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed types, use it, but it have problems

```
interface Cmd<T = string> { _T: T  }
interface CmdHandler<T = string> { _T: T }

declare class CmdOne implements Cmd<'CmdOne'> { _T: 'CmdOne' }
declare class CmdTwo implements Cmd<'CmdTwo'> { _T: 'CmdTwo' }
declare class CmdThree implements Cmd<'CmdThree'> { _T: 'CmdThree' }

declare class CmdHandlerOne implements CmdHandler<'CmdOne'> { _T: 'CmdOne' }
declare class CmdHandlerTwo implements CmdHandler<'CmdTwo'> { _T: 'CmdTwo' }
//declare class CmdHandlerThree implements CmdHandler<'CmdThree'> { _T: 'CmdThree' }

const cmds = [
    [CmdOne, CmdHandlerOne],
    [CmdTwo, CmdHandlerTwo],
    //[CmdThree, CmdHandlerThree],
];

export function CmdFactory<T>(cmd: Cmd<T>): CmdHandler<T> {
    const handle = cmds.find(pair => cmd instanceof pair[0])[1];
    return new handle as any; /// not good!
}

CmdFactory(new CmdOne)
CmdFactory(new CmdThree) /// Need error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Cmd%3CT%20%3D%20string%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20T%20%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20CmdHandler%3CT%20%3D%20string%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20CmdOne%20implements%20Cmd%3C'CmdOne'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdOne'%20%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20CmdTwo%20implements%20Cmd%3C'CmdTwo'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdTwo'%20%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20CmdThree%20implements%20Cmd%3C'CmdThree'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdThree'%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20CmdHandlerOne%20implements%20CmdHandler%3C'CmdOne'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdOne'%20%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20CmdHandlerTwo%20implements%20CmdHandler%3C'CmdTwo'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdTwo'%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2Fdeclare%20class%20CmdHandlerThree%20implements%20CmdHandler%3C'CmdThree'%3E%20%7B%20_T%3A%20'CmdThree'%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cmds%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BCmdOne%2C%20CmdHandlerOne%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BCmdTwo%2C%20CmdHandlerTwo%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%5BCmdThree%2C%20CmdHandlerThree%5D%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20CmdFactory%3CT%3E(cmd%3A%20Cmd%3CT%3E)%3A%20CmdHandler%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20handle%20%3D%20cmds.find(pair%20%3D%3E%20cmd%20instanceof%20pair%5B0%5D)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20handle%20as%20any%3B%20%2F%2F%2F%20not%20good!%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ACmdFactory(new%20CmdOne)%0D%0ACmdFactory(new%20CmdThree)%20%2F%2F%2F%20Need%20error%0D%0A)